# Type erasure with parameter defaults

Tags: scala, type-erasure, default-parameters

The following does not compile:

```
package play

object Stats2 {
  def variance(data: Seq[Double], dof: Int = 0): Double = {
    println("variance Double direct"); 1.0
  }
  def variance[T](data:Seq[T], dof: Int = 0)(implicit ex: T => Double): Double = {
    println("variance Double extracted"); 1.0
  }
}
```

The compiler says:

```
$ scalac erasure2.scala 
erasure2.scala:7: error: double definition:
method variance$default$2:[T]=> Int and
method variance$default$2:=> Int at line 4
have same type after erasure: ()Int
  def variance[T](data:Seq[T], dof: Int = 0)(implicit ex: T => Double): Double = {
                               ^
one error found
```

If **dof :Int = 0** is changed to **dof: Int**, the example compiles and works as expected.

It seems ugly that the presence or absence of a default parameter value changes whether the code is valid or not.

What is the explanation for why this really makes sense?

Comment: The first one makes complete sense as in Scala method overloading only by checking the first argument and because of type-erasure it is same, hence the error. Doing `dof:Int` is very weird. I don not see any reasoning in manual

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that when you use default arguments, its name and the method name is used to generate a static attribute, this way: `[methodName]$default$[argumentPosition]`, in your case it will be `variance$default$2`, so if both have default arguments, the compiler will try to generate 2 static attributes with the same name.

if the type of the other arguments in the method were used, this could be avoided. You may [submit a SIP](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/sip-submission.html) Proposal to change this behaviour in the compiler.

You can read more about this on this [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scala-user/FyQK3-cqfaY/fXLHr8QsW_0J)

If you want to check by yourself, try compiling your object with each method and inspect the class using `javap [XXX]`, where is the name of the object or class, in your case `javap Stats2`.
Your first method will give:

```
public final class Stats2 extends java.lang.Object{
    public static final int variance$default$2();
    public static final double variance(scala.collection.Seq, int);
}
```

and your second method will give:

```
public final class Stats2 extends java.lang.Object{
    public static final int variance$default$2();
    public static final double variance(scala.collection.Seq, int, scala.Function1);
}
```

finally, by removing the default value for dof in the second method, we get:

```
public final class Stats2 extends java.lang.Object{
    public static final double variance(scala.collection.Seq, int, scala.Function1);
}
```

So the `static final int variance$default$2()` is what is making the compilation to fail, which is generated by the default value.